# Event Tracking with Google Analytics in a Standalone HTML App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I work with internet connected touchscreens that can run HTML projects. The HTML projects must be self contained in that all assets like scripts, css, images, videos, etc... must be in the local file structure on the hardware in case the unit loses internet connectivity. The units have a built-in web server for this basic use with a chromium browser.

I'm wanting to track events on specified DOM elements using Google Analytics so those events can be recorded when the unit has an active internet connection.

For example... If a button is clicked to perform some sort of action on the page and in that action I want to include an audit call to send that event to my GA account. Pretty standard use of this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make this work on a page that isn't hosted on a typical website. Everything I'm finding doesn't deal with this specific scenario and always relies on a page hosted on a typical site.

How can I track events using Google Analytics on a standalone HTML page?

Thanks,
~Mike

Comment: How long do you expect connection losses to last ? How is a user/session defined in your scenario (since it looks like many users will be using a single device - e.g. is there a "start" button so you can programmatically determine when to start a new session/create a new user) ?

Comment: Connection loss can be seconds to days. I'm not too worried about caching the events that occur when the connection has dropped to resend once the connection is restored. There ins't any sort of login so the only indicator for a user session would be when the home page loads. A screen saver, non HTML, comes up after a few minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with sending your events by using Google Tag Manager to Google Analytics.It is quite easy to implement.

Try with adding the Google Tag Manager code, you get once you create the account in tag manager.And add your analytics property id to a custom variable in tag manager.Then create a page view type tag with analytics property id.

sample link for your reference https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en

Once you are able to link tag manager to your HTML page you can start tracking the page view event.Similarly, you can track other types of events.

Comment: if a self-contained standalone HTML page is shared via text like whatsapp, can we still get the analytics on that?  Things like, how many people viewed the page it reach and interactivity etc ?